# Unable to log in or write to WebDAV directory

Tags: macos, apache, webdav, cyberduck

I've configured WebDAV to run on my mac, by including the appropriate config file and throwing a config section in, like so:

```
Alias /SomeDav "/Users/user/Sites/Thing"

<Directory "/Users/user/Sites/Thing">
  Dav On

  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all

  AuthType Digest
  AuthName WebDAV-Realm
  AuthUserFile "/Users/user/webdav.passwd"

  <LimitExcept GET OPTIONS>
    require user "SomeWriter"
  </LimitExcept>
</Directory>
```

I then ran all the appropriate permission commands, and generated the password file, like so:

```
sudo htpasswd -c /Users/user/webdav.passwd "SomeWriter"
sudo chown -R www:www /Users/user/Sites/Thing/
sudo chown -R www:www /Users/user/webdav.passwd
```

If I try to connect to localhost/SomeDav, I succeed! I can see the contents of the directory in my browser (there's no request for authentication though...)

Now, if I try to connect to the site with CyberDuck, to test whether I can write to the directory, I run into issues. If I use SomeWriter as the user, and the appropriate password, CyberDuck keeps telling me my "Login Failed".

Am I missing something? Should this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also require a `DavLockDB` command

```
DavLockDB "/path/to/some/dir/DavLockDB"
```

Dav will create a file `/path/to/some/dir/DavLockDB`, so make sure that the directory `/path/to/some/dir/` is owned by `www` as well